# Sumar cantidad x a un campo de SQL server sin conocerlo

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server, la cual tiene la siguiente descripción:

```html
Id int 
Nombre varchar(50)
[1] float
[2] float
[3] float
[4] float
[5] float
[6] float
```

Ahora sucede que tengo un proyecto en c# en el cual utilizo la tabla anterior, en mi proyecto el usuario introduce un valor y ese valor deberá sumarse en cada una de las columnas [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6], solo si esas columnas ya tienen un valor, si son nulas no se modifican.

Ejemplo

```html
Id 1 
Nombre RAMON OCHOA
[1] NULL
[2] 12
[3] 34
[4] NULL
[5] NULL
[6] 25
```

Entonces si el usuario introduce el numero 1, deberá actualizarse el registro así:

```html
Id 1 
Nombre RAMON OCHOA
[1] NULL
[2] 13
[3] 35
[4] NULL
[5] NULL
[6] 26
```

Bien ahora la duda es que nose como hacer el update.

```html
if (textbox1.Text != "")
{
  double x = 0;
  if (double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out x))
  {
  x = x / 100; //valor a sumar
  con.Open();
  string sql="update tabla_ejemplo ";
  
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
  }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes con tu código para resolver este problema?

Comment: @Alfabravo nose como hacer el update en c#

Comment: El 1 se refiere al Id o a la cantidad que debe sumarse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
UPDATE pon_tabla SET nombre_columna = nombre_columna + 1 WHERE nombre_columna IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

El update para casos así es relativamente sencillo. La ventaja es que un valor nulo sumado a cualquier valor siempre resultará en nulo. Por lo tanto, no necesitas hacer ninguna validación adicional.

```
UPDATE t SET
    [1] = [1] + @Valor,
    [2] = [2] + @Valor,
    [3] = [3] + @Valor,
    [4] = [4] + @Valor,
    [5] = [5] + @Valor,
    [6] = [6] + @Valor
FROM MiTabla t
WHERE Id = @Id;
```

Debo decir que este es un modelomuy curioso y tal vez sea conveniente que alguien lo revise para optimizarlo. Pero eso queda fuera del alcance de la pregunta y respuesta.